# How to wait until networking by Alamofire has finished?

Tags: swift, networking, alamofire

I'd like to wait until networking by Alamofire has finished.

However, with the present code, it won't wait the finishing of networking, then move to next page by login() function.

Could you tell me how to wait until netwokirng by Alamofire finished?

```
@IBAction func signInWithTwitter(sender: UIButton) {

    Twitter.sharedInstance().logInWithCompletion { (session: TWTRSession!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if session != nil {
            let parameters = [
                "tw_id":session.userID,
                "tw_name" :session.userName,
                "tw_token":session.authToken
            ]

            Alamofire.request(.POST, self.uri.usersApi + "/tw_login", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
                .responseJSON { (request, response, data, error) in
                    var jsonObj = JSON(data!)
                    var uid = jsonObj["user_id"].int
                    self.defaults.setObject(uid, forKey: "uid")
            }

            self.login()

        } else {
            println(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't wait until the request is done, but rather put anything dependent on the request inside the `response` closure and let it run asynchronously, as demonstrated by iAshish, below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to put the login method inside the `Alamofire` block

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, self.uri.usersApi + "/tw_login", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
    .responseJSON { (request, response, data, error) in
        var jsonObj = JSON(data!)
        var uid = jsonObj["user_id"].int
        self.defaults.setObject(uid, forKey: "uid")
        self.login()
}
```